# How to get the x,y coordinates to extrude an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, 2d, coordinates

I am trying to detect the edges of an image (2D image) and extrude the edges of an image (3D image). I can simply extrude a random x,y coordinates using

```
x = randi(100,1,5);
y = randi(100,1,5);
x = x([1:end 1]);
y = y([1:end 1]);
bw = poly2mask(x,y,100,100);
figure;
subplot(121);
plot(x,y)
[xg,yg] = meshgrid(1:100);
zg = bw * 2;
subplot(122);
surfl(xg,yg,zg)
```

I can also get the x,y values of the coordinates from the pixel image using the following coordinates

```
A=double(imread('F:\01.jpg'));
imshow(A)
[height, width] = size(A)
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:width, 1:height);
```

But I am unable to use this x,y values as the input x,y values for extrusion. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This link](https://uk.mathworks.com/discovery/edge-detection.html) might help with the edge detection.

Comment: I am done with edge detection @meowgoesthedog Thanks